# Many to one LSTM input shape

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

My input data has 10 features and it is taken at 25 different timestamps. My output data consists of class labels. So, basically, I am having a many to one classification problem.

I want to implement an LSTM for this problem. Total training data consists of 10000 data points. How should the input and output format (shape) for this LSTM network be?

Comment: `X.shape = (10000,25,10)` and `y.shape = (10000, nr_classes)`?

Answer (score 2):

In the first layer of the model you should define `input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)`. So in your case `input_shape = (25,10)`.

Your actual input to the model will have shape `(1000,25,10)`.

You should also use `keras.np_utils.to_categorical` to convert your labels to one-hot-encoded vectors, so that they will become vectors with length X, where X is your class number. Every element will be equal to zero, except the one corresponding to the corresponding class.

Hope this helps!